# Pandas groupby multiindex when unique on first level: unexpected results

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Python version: 3.5.2; Pandas version: 0.23.1

I am noticing unexpected behavior when I groupby using two indices but each row is unique on the first index. The code I am executing on my data frame with column c is:

```
df.c.groupby(df.index.names).min()
```

Everything works as expected when the rows are not unique on the first index. To make this clear, I've included two versions below. Edit: Now including three versions!

**Version 1: Has the expected output**

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 4]], columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
df = df.set_index(['a','b']).sort_index()
```

Input:

```
     c
a b   
1 2  3
  2  4
4 5  6
```

Output:

```
a  b
1  2    3
4  5    6
```

**Version 2: Has the unexpected output**

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
df = df.set_index(['a','b']).sort_index()
```

Input:

```
     c
a b   
1 2  3
4 5  6
```

Output:

```
a    3
b    6
```

Expected Output:

```
a  b
1  2    3
4  5    6
```

**Version 3: Has expected output, but not expected with version 2 in mind.**

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 5, 6, 7]], columns=['a', 'b1', 'b2', 'c'])
df = df.set_index(['a','b1','b2']).sort_index()
```

Input:

```
         c
a b1 b2   
1 2  3   4
4 5  6   7
```

Output:

```
a  b1  b2
1  2   3     4
4  5   6     7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior is now changed in pandas. The output now matches the expected output in all cases.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a peek in to what is going on.  Take a look at the name of the series that gets getting passed into the "applied" function, f.

In the first case (Expected Results):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 4]], columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
df = df.set_index(['a','b']).sort_index()

def f(x):
    print(x)
    print('\n')
    print(min(x))
    print('\n')
    return min(x)
df.c.groupby(['a','b']).apply(f)
```

Output:

```
a  b
1  2    3
   2    4
Name: (1, 2), dtype: int64


3


a  b
4  5    6
Name: (4, 5), dtype: int64


6


Out[292]:

a  b
1  2    3
4  5    6
```

In the second case (unexpected results), note the name of the series passed in:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
df1 = df1.set_index(['a','b']).sort_index()
def f(x):
    print(x)
    print('\n')
    print(min(x))
    print('\n')
    return min(x)
df1.c.groupby(['a','b']).apply(f)
```

Output:

```
a  b
1  2    3
Name: a, dtype: int64


3


a  b
4  5    6
Name: b, dtype: int64


6


Out[293]:

a    3
b    6
Name: c, dtype: int64
```

It uses these series to build the resulting dataframe.  The naming of the series is the culprit due the nature of the data.  Why?  Well, we'll have to look into the code for that.

The idiomatic fix for this problem is use this syntax:

```
df1.groupby(df1.index.names)['c'].min()
```

Output:

```
a  b
1  2    3
4  5    6
Name: c, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think it may be helpful to include the results of my now added Version 3 here. With Version 3 in mind, I believe something very odd is going on here.

Comment: @RichardShadrach Nothing really strange is going on here.  Use the recommended syntax and you'll get the results you're expecting. `df3.groupby(df3.index.names)['c'].min()`

Comment: Is the syntax I was using not recommended? Or is it to do something other than what I intended? I find the difference in the result when I simply add a third level to the index mystifying and dangerous when code depends on the result having a certain index/values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `level` argument of groupby:

```
>>> df
     c
a b   
1 2  3
4 5  6

>>> df.c.groupby(level=[0,1]).min()
a  b
1  2    3
4  5    6
Name: c, dtype: int64
```

From the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)

> **level** : int, level name, or sequence of such, default None
>
> > If the axis is a MultiIndex (hierarchical), group by a particular level or levels

Comment: Indeed this gives the expected result (as does changing it to df.groupby(df.index.names).c.min()). However is the output I showed expected? Is there an explanation for it?

Comment: You can see the difference between the two strategies by looking at the list of groups when you groupby using each different method: `df.c.groupby(df.index.names).groups.keys()` groups by `a` and `b`, whereas `df.c.groupby(level=[0,1]).groups.keys()` groups by the values in the index, *i.e.* by `(1,2)` and `(4,5)`

Comment: Want more inconsistent behavior? Try selecting as a `DataFrame` with `df[['c']].groupby(df.index.names).min()`, which will provide the desired output.  I've run into this before, I have to believe it's not intended behavior.

Comment: @sacul: Sorry if I'm being dense here, but is getting back the keys ['a', 'b'] from your first line of code in your comment really something I should expect?

Comment: Well, those are the names of the indices, so I guess that yes, I would expect that, but to be honest, I'm not sure why you *don't* get that for your first example dataframe... Perhaps it's a bug, or I'm missing something somehwere

Comment: Okay - I had expected the keys would be the unique combination of the index values, not the indices themselves. Perhaps this is what I'm missing?